# Is there an Adaptive Instance Normalization layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was looking through the concept of Adaptive Instance Normalization and was wondering if there is a tf.keras.layers.AdaIN() somewhere.

If not, can someone please give any pointers to implement it using keras backend?

Comment: [Santi Iglesias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5333435) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054588) saying "This is a good implementation in Keras:
https://github.com/manicman1999/StyleGAN-Keras/blob/master/AdaIN.py"

Comment: Tensorflow has Instance Normalization that is `tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization`. For information visit [tensorflow addons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/layers_normalizations#instance_normalization_tutorial) library.